# Duplicated/Triplicated contacts in Mautic-Pipedrive

Tags: duplicates, contacts, mautic

I have my Mautic account that imports the **Pipedrive** persons. The major part of my contacts appear **duplicated**. The first is only created. The second one is created and updated. The two contacts are created at the same time.

Also, if I actualize a contact in Pipedrive, it only updates in one contact in Mautic (in the second one).

I tried with only the unique key of email, also with unique keys as Phone, email, IDPipedrive. All my contacts have email and Phone.

I also tried with Updatable contacts and still does not work!
Also sometimes there are contacts that are created 3 times, and some that are only one 1.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in Mautic 2.15.0. (beta version was released yesterday). The reason for duplication is when you configure both create and update webhooks for contacts. Pipedrive for some reason sends both webhooks at the same time when the contact is created in Pipedrive. This leads to a race condition and Mautic creates both. The documentation is updated to lead you to create only webhooks for updates.

https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/plugins/pipedrive.html

> Select updated to send to Mautic updated events for the given object. Do not select * as Pipedrive will send the updated events on create event too. If you select * the contacts/companies/users will be duplicated.

Mautic 2.15.0 will ignore the create webhooks and so the badly configured webhooks won't cause duplications.